# Many-To-Many optimistic locking failed

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have 2 DomainClasses that are in a Many-To-Many Relationship:

```
class Foo {
   static hasMany=[bars:Bar]
}
Class Bar {
   static belongsTo = [Foo]
   static hasMany=[foos:Foo]
}
```

Now i want to add a Bar to Foo like this:

```
Foo foo = Foo.get(params.fooId)
Bar bar = Bar.get(params.barId)
if(!foo || !bar)
   return render(template:'error')
foo.addToBars(bar)
foo.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
return render(template:'success')
```

This results in an `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`:

org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException:Object of class [test.Foo] with identifier [1]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [test.Foo#1]

Why does this Error occurs?

Comment: Should that be, in class Bar,  "static belongsTo = Foo" (no brackets)?

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to map the [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) in domains' mapping sections, according the following code:

```
class Foo {
   static hasMany = [bars:Bar]

   // etc

   static mapping = {
        // etc
        bars joinTable:[name: 'foo_bar', key: 'foo_id']     
    }
}
```

And the same thing for the other domain

```
class Bar {
   static belongsTo = Foo
   static hasMany = [foos:Foo]

   // etc

   static mapping = {
        // etc
        foos joinTable:[name: 'foo_bar', key: 'bar_id']     
    }
}
```

And finally, use `foo.addToBars(bar)` and save it.